# Create simple custom progression bar in React

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I'm trying to create my simple progression bar in React using CSS and `setInterval`. It's not working properly after 10%. Does anyone know why it is happening? Thanks

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const Loading = () => {

    const [percentage, setPercentage] = useState(0);

    const containerStyles = {
        height: 20,
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: "#e0e0de",
        borderRadius: 50,
        margin: 50
    }

    const fillerStyles = {
        height: '100%',
        width: `${percentage.toString()}%`,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        borderRadius: 'inherit',
        textAlign: 'right'
    }

    const labelStyles = {
        padding: 5,
        color: 'white',
        fontWeight: 'bold'
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const newPercentage = parseInt(percentage) + 1;
        setInterval(() => setPercentage(newPercentage), 1000);
    }, [percentage])

    return (
        <div style={containerStyles}>
            <div style={fillerStyles}>
                <span style={labelStyles}>{percentage}%</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Loading;
```

Comment: please define "not working".

Comment: @DanO did you have a chance to run the code? It stops increasing the percentage after 10%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store your interval in a constant and use the cleanup function to clear the last interval each time.

I'd also change how you handle setPercentage and use timeout instead of interval

Something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
     const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => 
        setPercentage(prevPercentage => prevPercentage + 1)
      , 1000);
   
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }, [setPercentage]);
```

Comment: What's the cleanup function? Could you please show me an example?

Comment: yes, edited. It's the function you return in useEffect

Comment: Could you please example why we need: ```return () => clearInterval(intervalID);``` ? Thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you. Is the timeout better than interval?

Comment: It's not about better, it's about what behaviour you want to have. I think that the timeout is more appropriate because eventually what you want is every second the timer will run and the function is going to re-render each time you set the state anyway. By the way, I can't see where you are stopping maybe you should add an if check inside that function to stop when the percentage reaches 100.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's not a real application, I'm just trying to understand more about React and JavaScript. Yes, when it reaches 100, I set the Percentage to 0, so it restarts.